# Tag Request: Galaxy S10

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I recently [made a post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/208769/cant-disable-icon-frames-on-galaxy-s10) regarding icon frame settings on my Galaxy S10+. As far as I'm aware, the setting issue I'm referring to is new to the S10 lineup.

I would like to request the addition of a **samsung-galaxy-s-10** tag so I can properly tag the above post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added the [samsung-galaxy-s-10](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-s-10) tag for you. Be welcome to edit its tag wiki and excerpt to make it more useful!

Comment: Thank you. I removed the request for a One UI tag so the post can be marked completed.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the feedback!